# install ncurses extensions on php7.0

Tags: php-7, php-extension, php-ncurses

I try install `ncurses` extensions for php7.0 but I get this error

```
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2/include -I/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2/main -I/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2 -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2/ncurses.c -o ncurses.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2/include -I/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2/main -I/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2 -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2/ncurses.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ncurses.o
/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2/ncurses.c:36:37: error: unknown type name ‘zend_rsrc_list_entry’
 static void ncurses_destruct_window(zend_rsrc_list_entry *rsrc TSRMLS_DC)
                                     ^
/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2/ncurses.c:45:36: error: unknown type name ‘zend_rsrc_list_entry’
 static void ncurses_destruct_panel(zend_rsrc_list_entry *rsrc TSRMLS_DC)
                                    ^
/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2/ncurses.c: In function ‘zm_startup_ncurses’:
/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2/ncurses.c:247:57: error: ‘ncurses_destruct_window’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  le_ncurses_windows = zend_register_list_destructors_ex(ncurses_destruct_window, NULL, "ncurses_window", module_number);
                                                         ^
/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2/ncurses.c:247:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/tmp/pear/download/ncurses-1.0.2/ncurses.c:249:56: error: ‘ncurses_destruct_panel’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  le_ncurses_panels = zend_register_list_destructors_ex(ncurses_destruct_panel, NULL, "ncurses_panel", module_number);
                                                        ^
Makefile:194: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «ncurses.lo»
make: *** [ncurses.lo] Ошибка 1
```

`ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «ncurses.lo»` is like `error in process run target`

Comment: `https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php?bug_id=71299&patch=ncurses-php7-support.patch&revision=latest` exist patch for support ncurses, @PaulCrovella

Comment: this link no longer exists. was there ever a fix for this ?

Comment: @duck see this link https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php?bug_id=71299&patch=nc%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Burses-php7-support.p%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Batch for latest version php not exist patch

Comment: @duck https://bugs.php.net/ don't work without VPN (I don't know why, may be country specific), you can download patch from [gist](https://gist.github.com/PrideSt/e550f52f79d5a80b335dd28454cb02fc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its an old post, but recently I have the same problem. I try the way that @mark-neyhart says in answer, but using the link that @Boshentz says in comment. And finally I can run ncurses with php8.3.

I followed these steps:

```
cd ~/
wget https://github.com/OOPS-ORG-PHP/mod_ncurses/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
unzip ~/master.zip
cd mod_ncurses-master
phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config
make
make install
rm -Rf ~/master ~/channels.xml
```

the idea is download last master branch from git repository, unzip and follow the same steps that @mark-neyhart says in his answer. More "simply", dont need to patch library, the only is to compile it.

also, i added a new image in docker-hub, that contains this configuration(if someone needs it):

**jakalagsp/php83-ncurses**

Comment: Thanks. Today, I install ncurses on php8.2 from pecl successfully.

Answer (score 4):

There is a patch which can be applied against v1.0.2 of ncurses for php to modify it for php 7.  Once the patch has been applied, the extension can be built and installed.

Required packages (these are Debian package names):
`php-cli`
`php-pear`
`php-dev`
`libncurses5-dev`
`ncurses-doc`
`libncursesw5-dev`

All following commands assume the user is logged in as root.  Packaging commands are specific to Debian.  These have been tested under Debian Stretch.

```
apt-get install php-cli php-pear php-dev libncurses5-dev ncurses-doc libncursesw5-dev
```

Use `pecl` to get v1.0.2 of ncurses, and `wget` to get the patch (as `ncurses.patch`).

```
cd /root
pecl download ncurses
mkdir /root/ncurses
cd /root/ncurses
tar -xvzf /root/ncurses-1.0.2.tgz
wget "https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php?bug_id=71299&patch=ncurses-php7-support-again.patch&revision=1474549490&download=1" -O ncurses.patch
```

Rename the `ncurses-1.0.2` directory to `ncurses-php5` because that is the name which the patch expects, and apply the patch.

```
mv ncurses-1.0.2 ncurses-php5
patch --strip=0 --verbose --ignore-whitespace <ncurses.patch
```

Build the ncurses extension.  This will build the `ncurses.so` file in `/root/ncurses/ncurses-php5/modules`.

```
cd ncurses-php5
phpize
./configure
make
```

Install the ncurses extension.  This will place the `ncurses.so` file in `/usr/lib/php/20151012`.  This location may differ in other distributions.

```
make install
```

Make the `ncurses.so` extension available to php 7.  These file locations may differ in other distributions.

```
cat <<'EndOfHereDoc' >/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ncurses.ini
; configuration for php ncurses module
; priority=20
extension=ncurses.so
EndOfHereDoc
ln --symbolic /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ncurses.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ncurses.ini
```

Verify that ncurses is indeed available.

```
php -m | grep ncurses
```

Once everything is working, the `/root/ncurses` directory, `/root/ncurses-1.0.2.tgz` file, and `/root/channels.xml` file can be removed.

Comment: thanks but I need try, after recive on your message.

Comment: Worked like a boss !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and stumbled upon this topic. Soluthions provided here didn't work for me, but I found another solution, whitch is available here: https://github.com/OOPS-ORG-PHP/mod_ncurses
It is patched and ready to compile.
Just sharing with others that will struggle with this as I did.

Comment: How do you set this up exactly?